# Yii2 - css of widgets are not working

Tags: file-upload, yii2, jquery-file-upload, yii-extensions

I am working with https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget widget of Yii2.
I used this widget in Backend (advanced template) and its working. Its js and css are automatically added to the html.
But when I use this in Frontend, only js are added to the html, but not css.
Strange thing.

```
use dosamigos\fileupload\FileUploadUI;

<?= FileUploadUI::widget([
    'model' => $mdlproductimage,
    'attribute' => 'image',
    'url' => ['product/image-upload', 'id' => $mdlproductimage->primgid],
    'gallery' => false,
    'fieldOptions' => [
            'accept' => 'image/*'
    ],
    'clientOptions' => [
            'maxFileSize' => 2000000
    ],
    // ...
    'clientEvents' => [
            'fileuploaddone' => 'function(e, data) {
                                    console.log(e);
                                    console.log(data);
                                }',
            'fileuploadfail' => 'function(e, data) {
                                    console.log(e);
                                    console.log(data);
                                }',
    ],
]);
?>
```

I know it is not the issue of Frontend/Backend. It may be any option which changed and I don't know about about it.

Edit 1: HTML Code

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Homepage</title>
<meta name="description" content="Homepage">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.offcanvas.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/off_canvas_nav.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/offCanvas.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/custom.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="./js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Provide the code you use to add this widget in the view for backend and frontend.

Comment: @Bizley : I added the code. same in frontend and backend.

Comment: Is the view of the same kind in both cases? I mean like not standard view in one case and modal in second? Or both are generated the same way?

Comment: Both are standard views. Modals are not there.

Comment: Check your server logs for any errors. Check assets folder permissions. Flush cache. I've got no more ideas...

Comment: no errors in log. asset folder permission is not a problem at all, cache flushed and checked again. This problem is occurs with other widget also. I was using ```kartik-v/file-upload``` but just because of this problem I try the above given file upload widget.. But no luck.. (same widget ```kartik-v & 2amigos``` both working in backend).

Comment: Have you got different configuration of AssetManager?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130481/discussion-between-kishor10d-and-bizley).

Comment: @Bizley : I checked in configuration and my controllers as well. Not any custom configuration in AssetManager.

Comment: I'm sorry but it looks like you need to debug the code in order to find the source of problem.

Comment: Can you update your question with HTML code you've got between `<head>` and `</head>` in your frontend layout file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing

```
<?php $this->head() ?>
```

in the layout `<head>` section. Assets registered to be placed in the head part of HTML can not be rendered.